# Redux action not triggering particular reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, aws-amplify, i18next

I have the following redux set-up:

**Actions --> actions.js**

```
import { SET_ADMIN, SET_USER, SET_LNG } from "./actionTypes";

export const setAdmin = (isAdmin) => {
  return {
    type: SET_ADMIN,
    payload: {
      isAdmin,
    },
  };
};

export const setUser = (user) => {
  return {
    type: SET_USER,
    payload: {
      user,
    },
  };
};

export const setLanguage = (lng) => {
  return {
    type: SET_LNG,
    payload: {
      lng,
    },
  };
};
```

**Reducers -> globals.js**

```
import { SET_ADMIN, SET_USER, SET_LNG } from "../actionTypes";

const initialState = {
  isAdmin: false,
  user: {},
  lng: "en",
};

function globals(state = initialState, action) {
  console.log(state, action); // --> Not fired on lng update
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_ADMIN: {
      const { isAdmin } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        isAdmin,
      };
    }

    case SET_USER: {
      const { user } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        user,
      };
    }

    case SET_LNG: {
      const { lng } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        lng,
      };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default globals;
```

**Reducers -> index.js**

```
import globals from "./globals";

export default globals;
```

**Action Types**

```
export const SET_ADMIN = "SET_ADMIN";
export const SET_USER = "SET_USER";
export const SET_LNG = "SET_LNG";
```

**Store ->  store.js**

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";

export default createStore(rootReducer);
```

I then have a language selector component that should set the global language choice

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { MenuItem, FormControl, Select } from "@mui/material";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { setLanguage } from "../../Redux/actions";

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => {
  return {
    root: {
      flexGrow: 1,
      height: "5em",
      marginTop: "10px",
      marginBottom: "10px",
      textAlign: "right",
    },
  };
});

function LanguageSelect(props) {
  const { language } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [lng, setLng] = useState(language);

  function handleChange(event) {
    const newLanguage = event.target.value;
    setLanguage(newLanguage);
    return setLng(newLanguage);
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <FormControl>
        <Select
          labelId="select-language-label"
          id="select-language"
          value={lng}
          displayEmpty
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value={"en"}>English</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={"es"}>Spanish</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { lng: language } = state;
  return { language };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { setLanguage })(LanguageSelect);
```

And then in a AuthWrapper component using `aws amplify` I want to use the language selector to set the language for the login page:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Amplify, { I18n } from "aws-amplify";
import { Authenticator, View } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";
import "@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css";
import { translations } from "@aws-amplify/ui";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import App from "./App";
import "./App.css";
import LanguageSelect from "./Components/LanguageSelect";

/*global CONFIG */
Amplify.configure(CONFIG.AWS);

const components = {
  Header() {
    return (
      <View as="section">
        <LanguageSelect />
      </View>
    );
  },
};

const placeholderSpanishVocab = {
  "Sign In": "Iniciar sesión", // Tab header
  "Sign in": "Iniciar sesión", // Button label
  "Sign in to your account": "Bienvenido!",
  "Forgot your password?": "Restablecer la contraseña",
};

const AuthWrapper = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  const { language } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    I18n.putVocabularies(translations);
    I18n.putVocabulariesForLanguage("es", placeholderSpanishVocab);
    I18n.setLanguage(language);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    I18n.setLanguage(language);
  }, [language]);

  return (
    <Authenticator components={components}>
      {(props) => {
        return <App {...props} />;
      }}
    </Authenticator>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { lng: language } = state;
  return { language };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(AuthWrapper);
```

The set user and set admin actions are used in the App component, and seem to fire and update the redux state without issue, but for some odd reason I can't quite pinpoint, the set language is not updating the redux state.

Any ideas why this would be happening?

Comment: Would you mind sharing a link to your repo?

Comment: Afraid I can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the way I dispatched the action in the LanguageSelect component solved the issue, but I would still like to understand why this particular action failed and not the setUser or setAdmin.

```
function handleChange(event) {
    const newLanguage = event.target.value;
    props.dispatch({ type: "SET_LNG", payload: { lng: newLanguage } }); // --> changed this to get it working
    return setLng(newLanguage);
  }
```